# Given an entire function which is real on the real axis and imaginary on the imaginary axis, prove that it is an odd function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Given an entire function which is real on the real axis and imaginary on the imaginary axis, prove that it is an odd function.

By a Corollary: If $f$ analytic in a region symmetric with respect to the real axis and if $f$ is real for real $z$, then $f(z) = \overline{f(\bar z)} $.

So that, $f(z) = u(x+iy) + iv(x+iy) = u(x-iy) - iv(x-iy)$
$f(-z) = u(-x-iy) + iv(-x-iy) = u(-x+iy) - iv(-x+iy)$
$-f(-z) = -u(-x+iy) + iv(-x+iy)$

It looks close to the answer but what else can I do by using Schwartz reflection principle??

Comment: What does $f(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$ give you for purely imaginary $z$?

Comment: @DanielFischer $f(-z) = -u(x-iy) + iv(x-iy)$ ? I am not sure...

Comment: If $z$ is purely imaginary, the premise is that $f(z)$ is purely imaginary. For a purely imaginary $w$, what is $\overline{w}$ (keeping in mind that we want to prove that $f$ is odd as a guidance for what may be relevant).

Comment: But even though I can say $f(w) = \overline{f(-w)} = - f(-w)$, but I have no idea how to use it...

Comment: What can you say about the two functions $f$ and $g \colon z \mapsto -f(-z)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the Taylor series of $f(z)$
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n
$$
Since $f(z)= \overline{f(\bar z)}$, all $a_n$ are real. Since $f$ maps imaginary on the imaginary axis
\begin{align}
f(iy)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_ni^ny^n&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n}i^{2n}y^{2n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n+1}i^{2n+1}y^{2n+1}
\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}a_{2n}\:y^{2n}+i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}a_{2n+1}\:y^{2n+1}
\end{align}
is imaginary. So
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}a_{2n}\:y^{2n}=0
$$
which means $a_{2n}=0$ for all $n$. So $f(z)$ is odd.

Comment: There is an error with the indices, it should be in the first line $f(iy)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n}i^{2n}y^{2n}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n+1}i^{2n+1}y^{2n+1}$ and then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^na_{2n}y^{2n}+ i\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^na_{2n+1}y^{2n+1}$. Other choices are possible as well, however like it is written it has the starting index problem and the $1/2$ once too much problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have fixed it