# Prove that $f(z) $ is an odd function when $z \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given an entire function which is real on the real axis and imaginary on the imaginary axis, prove that it is an odd function i,e $f(-z)= -f(z)$

My attempt :  Here two cases will be possible

$1.$ when $z= x$

$2.$ when $z = ix $

I have no any issue when $z=ix$  and solution is alreaday given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1534901/557708)

but i have some issue when $z=x$

$$f(x) = \overline{ f(\bar x) }$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\bar a_nz^n \implies a_n=\bar a_n$$

\begin{align}
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{2n}x^{2n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}
\end{align}

Here  $f(x)$  is both  even and odd

so here  we are getting  contradiction that  $f(z)$  is odd that mean $f(x)$ is not even function

Comment: Are you confusing even with entire?

Comment: @Blazej im not confusing.. see the deifinition an entire function is called real if it maps the real line into itself.

Comment: @jasmine you can consider z as complex number, and the steps on the answer work. you don't have to separate it into two steps, (real and imaginary)

Comment: I've deleted my anwswer because it doesn't address your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1534901/557708)

The guy first assumed z is only imaginary ($z = iy$). Then he used that to show that all even $a$'s should be zero. That is $a_{2n}=0$.
This means
$$f(z) = a_1z^1 + a_3z^3 + a_5z^5 + ...$$
for all $z = x +iy $

Then he used that to show that the function is odd for any $z$ ($z = x+iy$)

That is:
$$
f(-z) = a_1(-z)^1 + a_3(-z)^3 + a_5(-z)^5 + ... = - (a_1z^1 + a_3z^3 + a_5z^5 + ...) = -f(z)
$$

Comment: thanks that mean  when $z= x$ we can directly say that $f(-z)=-f(z)$

Comment: @jasmine no. I didn't say that. The guy who answered the question used the case where z is imaginary to show that all $a_{2n}$ are zeros. Then he used that fact to include for all z, including real ones

Comment: I'll edit my answer to make it clear

Comment: @jasmine is it clear now?

Comment: wait  let me think more

Comment: ookks @Aven  that  mean  he removed  $i$  and   $f(y)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}a_{2n+1}\:y^{2n+1}$

Comment: i understand  now ...  u can check my answer  @Aven

Answer (score 0):

From this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1534901/557708) we have  show that

$a_{2n}=0$ for all $n$.

now  $f(x+iy)=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x+iy)^n= a_0+a_1(x+iy)^1 + a_2(x+iy)^2+....... 
$
give  odd  function

Comment: yes, but in the series all even $a$ are zero. so only odd numbered $a$ are left. And the sum of any odd functions is an odd function